# Sanding between coats of Poly : Help! I scratched the first surface of poly with 150 grit

Tags: sanding, polyurethane

I know, 150 was not the correct grit to sand poly with.  I listened to someone i shouldn't have.

I stained my Walnut Bar, and then put on my first coat of poly.  It looked lovely.  Then I sanded....and now it looks hideous.  SO many scratches.  This has never happened to me before!  How can i get the scratches out? Do I need to slowly increase the grit?  220 / 350 / 400 etc ...Am i going to have to sand the entire thing and stain it again??? Ahhhhhhh

I did a little test corner of a 2nd layer of poly, and obviously the scratches are still there, less so - but in the wrong light, its glaring.

Comment: How much time between poly application and sanding? And were you machine or hand-sanding?

Comment: And this is totally fixable. You will need to step up through the grits.

Comment: *"150 was not the correct grit to sand poly with"* Actually 150 can be totally appropriate to sand varnish with, depending on what you're doing, how much you sand with it, how hard you press, the thickness of the varnish layer and of course whether you're sanding by hand or with a machine (and then very much, which sander). Anyway, this Q has been asked an answered here multiple times before, just look at the **Related** section for a start.

Comment: I waited over 24 hours to sand the poly.  @AloysiusDefenestrate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix very light scratches in polyurethane finish?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/how-to-fix-very-light-scratches-in-polyurethane-finish) See also [this](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14314/not-leave-scratches-in-poly-to-begin-with/14316#14316) Answer in particular.